# Retorno na View da Paginação a partir de Array em Laravel/Paginate::make()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, paginação

Quando crio uma paginação manualmente, está dando erro, ele não cria na view a quantidade de elementos exatas conforme eu determino.

No meu controlador:

```
public function getIndex(){
    $fileClass = FileClass::with(['FileServico'])
        ->where('status','=','PR')
        ->where('id_cliente','=',1)
        ->orderBy('id_file','DESC')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    foreach($fileClass as $fileArr){
        foreach($fileArr['file_servico'] as $file){
            $f[] = $file;
        }
    }

    return View::make('home')
        ->with('fileClass',Paginator::make($f, count($f),2));
}
```

Na view eu faço a iteração normalmente para imprimir os dados e os mesmos são impressos, o paginador é criado normalmente em baixo e faz a contagem exata conforme eu determino, porém, a tabela que é criada não trás os elementos exatos.

```
@foreach($fileClass as $f)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $f['id_file'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

E o paginador está certinho, aparece normalmente:

```
@section('pagination')
    <section id="pagination">
        {{ $fileClass->links() }}
    </section>
@stop
```

Na hora de imprimir a quantidade de elementos por página ele imprime todos os elementos, abaixo é apresentado o paginador normalmente, mas não existe a paginação em si.

Comment: Eu resolvi o meu problema através desse tutorial: **https://arjunphp.com/laravel-5-pagination-array/** talvez seja útil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) acredito ser mais prático:

```
 $resultado = DB::table('file_class')
    ->join('file_servico', 'file_class.id', '=', 'file_servico.id') 
    ->where('file_class.status','=','PR')
    ->where('file_class.id_cliente','=',1)
    ->orderBy('file_class.id_file','DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

O `$resultado` já sai paginado sem problemas só atribuir, para o seu `View::make`:

```
return View::make('home')
        ->with('fileClass', $resultado);
```

Uma boa prática, seria fazer isso em um classe e só chamar o método:

```
class RepFileClass
    public function toListPaginate()
    {           
        return 
            DB::table('file_class')
                ->join('file_servico', 'file_class.id', '=', 'file_servico.id') 
                ->where('file_class.status','=','PR')
                ->where('file_class.id_cliente','=',1)
                ->orderBy('file_class.id_file','DESC')
                ->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

*Referências:*

- [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)
- [Basic Join Statement](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins)
- [Paginating Database Results](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage)

Comment: Mas o segundo parâmetro não é total de items??? Se eu fizer essa alteração, ele pára de funcionar, na documentação diz que a quantidade por página é o terceiro parâmetro, tem alguma outra recomendação? Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Desculpa eu me enganei... eu vou editar como seria a sua resposta mais ou menos ... existe uma maneira melhor mais vou seguir o seu jeito ai!

Comment: @EwertonMelo o jeito que você ta fazendo ta meio errado, tipo vai ser gambiarra e acredito não ser legal, poderia ser feito com Query Builder? se sim me passe o nome das duas tabelas que é um palito? ou então join no Eloquent também dá?